# Setting a check box as checked or unchecked based on a value in a model on page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I have a check box on a form like so

```
 <%= check_box_tag(:monday) %>
```

When submitted, the checkbox updates a model. When the user loads the page, I would like the checkbox to be checked if the model value for 'monday' is true and unchecked if the model value is false.

I'm leaning towards a helper method that will return true or false for the value, which should be straightforward, but how do I call that method from the view and get the true/false value back on the page load?

EDIT:

```
<%= form_for @recur_breakfast_plate, url: update_recur_breakfast_plate_path do |f| %>
                  </br>
                  <div class='field form-group'>
                    <div class='checkbox-inline'>
                      <%= check_box_tag(:monday) %>
                      <%= label_tag(:monday, "Monday") %>
                    </div>

                    <div class='checkbox-inline'>
                      <%= check_box_tag(:tuesday) %>
                      <%= label_tag(:tuesday, "Tuesday") %>
                    </div>

                    <div class='checkbox-inline'>
                      <%= check_box_tag(:wednesday) %>
                      <%= label_tag(:wednesday, "Wednesday") %>
                    </div>

                    <div class='checkbox-inline'>
                    <%= check_box_tag(:thursday) %>
                    <%= label_tag(:thursday, "Thursday") %>
                    </div>

                    <div class='checkbox-inline'>
                      <%= check_box_tag(:friday) %>
                      <%= label_tag(:friday, "Friday") %>
                    </div>
                    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-xs btn-success" %>

                  </div>
 <% end %>
```

The form_for associated with the question^

Comment: Have you tried using ```form_for``` and the corresponding methods?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html

Comment: You should be getting this for "free" with rails.  Can you post the form and the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Rails should *set* `@recur_breakfast_plate` in a before_action which would be executed before the *edit* action. This way all the fields would have the right values.

Anyway you can try

```
<%= check_box_tag :day, @recur_breakfast_plate.day %>
```

Comment: Just tried this, but it didn't make any difference at all. Could the value of @recur_breakfast_plate.day be used to set a default 'checked' value in the check_box_tag?

Comment: Yes, but you have to replace _day_ with the right day. The second parameter you pass to check_box_tag will result in the value of the input. You should check examples [in the doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag).

Comment: Disregard my previous comment, I was creating a new RecurringBreakfastPlate in my controller when the page loads instead of loading the model of the current_user. It is working now!